# Modify layer's renderer with pyQGIS (QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer)

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, style, color-ramp, categorized-renderer

I want to modify the color ramp of my layer in pyQGIS like I would do it in the layer properties :

[image: color ramp in QGIS style]

I identified `QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer().updateColorRamp(ramp=color_ramp)` as the function to update it, but I can't link it to my maplayer. How can I access the renderer of a layer ?

Comment: Assuming you have a reference to a layer such as `lyr`, you can call the renderer with: `r = lyr.renderer()`

Comment: and then I can apply the `updateColorRamp` on it ? Because `QgsFeatureRenderer` doesn't seem to have such function

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422030/128665). Hopefully, it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matt, I got the working code :

```py
renderer = mylayer.renderer()
if isinstance(renderer, QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer):
    if color_ramp is None:
        default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
        color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp('Spectral')  # Spectral color ramp
        color_ramp.invert()
    renderer.updateColorRamp(ramp=color_ramp)

    if myfield is not None:
        renderer.setClassAttribute(myfield)
        mylayer.setRenderer(renderer)
        mylayer.triggerRepaint()
```